# Fixed column value when using JPA, Criteria API and a static metamodel

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api, metamodel

Given the following:

```
CriteriaQuery<SomeDTO> cQuery;
CriteriaBuilder cb;
Root<SomeClass> r;
...
cQuery.select(cb.construct(SomeDTO.class,
  "FIXED VALUE",
   r.get(SomeClass_.someValue)
));
```

Is there a way inwith the JPA criteria api and a static metamodel to create a select, which returns a fixed value for one column?
The respective SQL should be something like

```
SELECT 'FIXED VALUE', someValue FROM someClassTable WHERE ...;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you referring 'FIXED VALUE' to fixed length of column or some constant which should be return while executing select query

Comment: The latter, a fixed value (e.g. a certain string) which should be returned for all found rows.

Comment: OK, I think while I wrote the response to your comment, I found the answer by myself: The word "literally" popped up in my head and looking for that in the criteria builder actually provided me with CriteriaBuilder.literal()! That is what I was looking for! Anyway, @NayanWadekar, if you write that as an answer, I will grant you the "correct answer" mark as it was your question which provided me with the missing information!

Comment: I have just added comment to get more information as it was little bit confusing. As you have resolved it, you can always answer your own question, but I think there is some forced delay for doing it, not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I was looking for is `CriteriaBuilder.literal()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#literal%28T%29